# Set as String From HTML and PHP Line of Code

Tags: php, string, type-conversion

i have stuck to create a line of code in html combined with php as fully string

what i want to place the string to a variable so it can be echoed by php

original html + php syntax:

```
   <a href="JavaScript:newPopup('<?php echo $site_path; ?>/transactions/details.php?id=<?php echo $r['idtr_inventory']; ?>');"><i class="icon-info-sign"></i></a>
```

I assign that line of code to some var, ex: $myVar

I have tried this:

```
$myVar= "<a href='JavaScript:newPopup('<?php echo ".(string)$site_path; ."?>/transactions/details.php?id=<?php echo ". (string)$r['idtr_inventory']; . "?>');'><i class='icon-info-sign'></i></a>";
```

but still errors. Is there any proper way to make the line of code fully capable of string?

thanks.

Comment: For the strings with more quotes in it you can use php `HEREDOC`

Answer (score 1):

Use PHP HEREDOC as :

```
$foo = <<<EOT
<some markup and php variables>
EOT;
```

Comment: hi lekhnath, this still give me error, but thanks for commenting. I've resolve this issue myself.

Answer (score 0):

It should be like this :

```
// you dont need to put the php tag while initializing a variable with string + value of another variable
$myVar= "<a href=\"JavaScript:newPopup('".$site_path."/transactions/details.php?id=". $r['idtr_inventory']."');\"><i class='icon-info-sign'></i></a>";
```

I hope this can be of some help.

Comment: hi saran, the variable it self is missing from the syntax, so the id like: "idtr_inventory" is not shown. just ...details.php?id=<missing var>. It have been resolved now. But thanks for commenting